# Screen orientation not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

i write this code:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
```

insert the config.xml file in cordova project for android platform, i also try :

```
<platform name="android">
 <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
 </platform>
```

but not working.The screen rotation work for landscape and portrait also. i want only portrait. Any suggestions? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in your config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
   <preference name="Orientation" value="sensorPortrait"/>
</platform>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I try it but also not work